# Undefined variable, assigned inside if/else in render method React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple component which gets props from a parent:

```
render(){
    const {message} = this.props;

    if(message){
        let {title, text} = message;
    } else {

        let title= 56;
        let text= 34;
        console.log('inside')
        console.log(title);
    }

    console.log('outside');
    console.log(lat);

    return( // JSX) // The vars are not used
```

When I run it, `message` is undefined and I see in the console - `inside` and `54`.
Right after that `outside` and `ReferenceError: title is not defined`.
If I copy/paste `let title= 56;` outside if/else, everything works. 
For debugging in all cases `message` is undefined.
 why is that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables defined with `let` are block scoped, so they will not exist outside of your `if`/`else` blocks. You could define them before the `if`/`else` and just assign values to them there instead.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { message } = this.props;
    let title, text;

    if (message) {
      title = message.title;
      text = message.text;
    } else {
      title = 56;
      text = 34;
    }

    return <>{/* ... */}</>;
  }
}
```